# Why does `typeof false || undefined` returns "boolean"

Tags: javascript

I've just executed the following in console:

```
typeof false || undefined // "boolean"
```

While I expected it to return "undefined", since

```
typeof undefined // "undefined"
```

Why did it return "boolean"? Isn't the `OR` operator supposed to return the last argument if previous evaluated to falsey values? So that `false || undefined` returns `undefined` and `typeof` is executed against `undefined`?

Comment: `typeof false` returns string `boolean` which is true

Comment: @Maxx, I know that, my question is in the last paragraph

Comment: `typeof (false || undefined)` is your solution

Comment: The problem is; first evaluated is not "falsey", it's a string. For more information about typeof https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not observing **operator precedence!**

```
> typeof false || boolean  // (typeof false) || boolean
"boolean"
> typeof (false || boolean)
"undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` operator returns the left argument as long as it isn't falsy.

In your example, we've got this:

`(typeof false) || undefined`

`typeof false` returns `"boolean"`, which isn't falsy, so it is returned rather than `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code :

```
typeof false || undefined
```

`typeof false` will return "boolean" , so it will become 
`"boolean" || undefined`

The final output will be 
"boolean"